# How to make loot tables work in 1.14?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been trying to set up a loot table for a chest. For some reason it doesn't work.
I put the .json file into "*datapacks/loottables/data/minecraft/loot_tables/chests/*".
There is a "*pack.mcmeta*" file in the correct folder right next to the data folder. The game does list this datapack when running the command `/datapack list`.
I named the file "*buried_treasure.json*".

Here is the command I used:  `/setblock ~ ~ ~  chest{LootTable:"minecraft:loot_tables/chests/buried_treasure.json"}`
The chest comes out empty.

Here is the json file:

```
{
  "type": "minecraft:chests",
  "pools":
  [
    {
      "rolls":
      {
        "min": 1,
        "max": 4
      },
      "entries":
      [
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "minecraft:bread",
          "weight": 60,
          "functions":
          [
            {
              "function": "set_count",
              "count":
              {
                "min": 5,
                "max": 15
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "minecraft:carrot",
          "weight": 65,
          "functions":
          [
            {
              "function": "set_count",
              "count": 1
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "minecraft:cooked_beef",
          "weight": 31,
          "functions":
            [
              {
                "function": "set_count",
                "count":
                {
                  "min": 1,
                  "max": 10
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "item",
            "name": "minecraft:arrow",
            "weight": 1,
            "quality": 50,
            "functions":
            [
              {
                "function": "set_count",
                "count":
                {
                  "min": 3,
                  "max": 10
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "item",
            "name": "minecraft:stick",
            "weight": 51,
            "functions":
            [
              {
                "function": "set_count",
                "count":
                {
                  "min": 5,
                  "max": 20
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "item",
            "name": "minecraft:string",
            "weight": 50,
            "functions":
            [
              {
                "function": "set_count",
                "count":
                {
                  "min": 5,
                  "max": 15
                }
              } 
            ] 
          },
          {
            "type": "item",
            "name": "minecraft:iron_ingot",
            "weight": 30,
            "functions":
            [
              {
                "function": "set_count",
                "count":
                {
                  "min": 2,
                  "max": 13
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "item",
            "name": "minecraft:redstone",
            "weight": 1,
            "quality": 20,
            "functions":
            [
              {
                "function": "set_count",
                "count":
                {
                  "min": 2,
                  "max": 11
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "item",
            "name": "minecraft:obsidian",
            "weight": 17,
            "functions":
            [
              {
                "function": "set_count",
                "count":
                {
                  "min": 1,
                  "max": 8
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "item",
            "name": "minecraft:gold_ingot",
            "weight": 10,
            "functions":
            [
              {
                "function": "set_count",
                "count":
                {
                  "min": 1,
                  "max": 6
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "item",
            "name": "minecraft:iron_helmet",
            "weight": 8,
            "functions":
            [
              {
                "function": "set_count",
                "count": 1
              }
            ]
          },
          "type": "item",
          "name": "minecraft:iron_chestplate",
          "weight": 5,
          "functions":
          [
            {
              "function": "set_count",
              "count": 1
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "minecraft:iron_leggings",
          "weight": 5,
          "functions":
          [
            {
              "function": "set_count",
              "count": 1
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "minecraft:iron_boots",
          "weight": 6,
          "functions":
          [
            {
              "function": "set_count",
              "count": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything else?

Comment: …like a simpler loot table or using one of the defaults to test?

Comment: I have tested much simpler loot tables but they don't work either. I mean loot tables with just a single item.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the solution is as simple as changing the loot table name from

"minecraft:loot_tables/chests/buried_treasure.json"

to

"minecraft:chests/buried_treasure"

Now everything appears in the chest as things should.